# Output Time Sink amplitude in GNU

Tags: gnuradio

Is there anyway that I can output a Time Sink's amplitude using a TCP Sink or, File Sink using GNU Radio?

Comment: That makes no sense. The time sink just displays the samples you put in. So you would just connect its input to the File Sink or TCP Sink instead.